# Custom <error-page> is being ignored (only for certain paths)

Tags: tomcat, jsf-2

For some reason my

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/error/error.html</location>
</error-page>
```

which is defined in *tomcat\conf\web.xml* is being ignored when I'm trying to access the following path

*WebAppName/javax.faces.resource/anyFileName.jsf*

I know that its cause of the *javax.faces.resource* prefix and the *.jsf* suffix combined together...

cause if I change one of them I do get the custom error page

I do know that its not a common path to pick, but still I wonder how can I make it use my custom `error-page`

b.t.w , I'm using *myfaces 2.0.11*

---

One way could be

1) Create a custom filter

2) Get path of the requested resource

3) Check if path exists `file.exists()`

4) If not exist call `response.sendError(404, "Cannot find " + path);` otherwise call `chain.doFilter(req, res);`

But I don't like this approach at all, it's an *OverKill* IMO...

So still wonder if there is a better way...